# trying to resize list items so they are all equal size

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my list items all the same width.  I've tried setting the widths in the css and nothing changes.  Can anyone figure this out?
Here is an image to show what I am talking about:
[image]

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="content-wrapper" id="container">
    <header>logo
        <nav>navigation</nav>
    </header>
    <div class="clear-fix"></div>
    <div id="body">
        <section class="main-content">
            <section class="leftPane">
                    <h2>Categories</h2>

            </section>
            <section class="rightPane">
                <div class="checkout">
                        <h1>Checkout</h1>

                    <ul class="steps">
                        <li><a href="http://localhost:59213/Cart">
                                <div id="step0" class="arrow_box_grey">
                                    Shopping Cart</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost:59213/Cart/Student">
                                <div id="step1" class="arrow_box_grey">
                                    Student</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost:59213/Cart/Delivery">
                                <div id="step2" class="arrow_box_grey">
                                    Delivery</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div id="step3" class="arrow_box_green">Payment</div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div id="step4" class="arrow_box_blue">Finish</div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </section>
            <div class="clear-fix"></div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here if my fiddle with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/M74Em/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change this style:

```
.main-content .checkout ul.steps li div {
    display: inline;
    width: 1000px;
}
```

You can't set widths for inline elements so try this:

```
.main-content .checkout ul.steps li div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/M74Em/1/)

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you, good to know that about inline elements.

Answer (score 0):

From [twBootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), applied to `<ul>`'s [(demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/M74Em/2/):

```
.ul-justified {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.ul-justified > li {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    width: 1%;
}
```

and slap `.ul-justified` to any ul-list you want aligned, and you get equal width `<li>`'s automatically fit parent ul's width.